# Composite materials

Tags: classical-mechanics, optical-materials, material-science

I'm reading about brake pad material. The paper said

> ...according to original equipment manufacturer (OEM) the pads are made by combining five types of materials: binders, abrasive, performance, filler, and structure...

So I want to understand: what are the advantages of each material in the composite? Like the abrasive added to increase hardness. What about the other?

Please help me!

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_pad#Materials) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abrasive is intended to increase friction. You want your brake pads to have (and retain) a certain shape, so you use some structure material that resists well to changes in temperature. Not sure what performance material is supposed to be. In order to limit the costs, in places where no structural integrity is threatened, and no friction exists, you can use a filler material. to bind it all together, you use binders